# Ansible: --limit on groups created with group_by?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using ansible to manage hosts on GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine).   I've got dynamic inventory working great using gce.py.   I then use group_by to create groups for each cluster:

```
- group_by:
    key: "{{gce_metadata['cluster-name']}}"
```

But the fact that I can't use these dynamically created groups with `--limit` is significantly hampering my style:

```
 $ ansible-playbook -l mycluster playbook.yaml
 ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts
```

Even cooler would be to able to use `group_by` groups with ansible ad-hoc commands...

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I'm modifying gce.py#group_instances, adding this clause:

```
        for entry in node.extra['metadata']['items']:
            if entry['key'] == 'cluster-name':
                clusters.add(entry['value'])
                if entry['value'] in groups:
                    groups[entry['value']].append(name)
                else:
                    groups[entry['value']] = [name]
```